How does ingress distribution work across partitions in Azure Event Hubs?
I'm trying to understand how ingress distribution works across partitions in Azure Event Hubs, specifically in relation to partition allocation and throughput.
I know that the number of partitions in an Event Hub does not affect the pricing, which is instead determined by the number of throughput units (TUs) for the standard tier, processing units (PUs) for the premium tier, or capacity units (CUs) for the dedicated tier. For example, whether an Event Hub has 1 partition or 32 partitions, the cost is the same if the namespace is set to one TU.
From my understanding, partitions are a data organization mechanism that enables parallel publishing and consumption of events. The recommendation is to balance the number of scaling units (TUs, PUs, or CUs) with the number of partitions to achieve optimal throughput. Generally, it's suggested that each partition can handle up to 1 MB/s of throughput, so if my use case requires 20 MB/s of ingress, I should configure at least 20 partitions.
However, what’s not clear to me is how ingress is actually distributed across these partitions:

If I’m using partition keys: Does this mean that each partition will always receive exactly 1 MB/s of data if I have 20 partitions and 20 MB/s of ingress, or is the distribution of ingress more dynamic?
Without partition keys or specific partition IDs: Does Event Hubs automatically balance the ingress load evenly across partitions, or are there situations where some partitions might handle more traffic than others?

Any clarification on how the assignment of ingress to partitions is managed, especially in scenarios with high ingress rates and multiple partitions, would be greatly appreciated!

Publishing of events can be done in three different ways:

Automatic assignment:  When no partition key or partition id is used, the event batch is sent to the Event Hubs gateway service which then assigns a partition using a round-robin approach and forwards the batch to the assigned partition.  Note that the entire batch is sent to the same partition; the service does not extract individual events from the batch and assign them round-robin.

Using a partition key: The partition key is set for a batch of events, which is sent to the Event Hubs gateway service.  The gateway performs a hash operation on the partition key to determine which partition to forward the batch to.  Here again, the entire batch is sent to the same partition.  It is not possible to set different partition keys for events in the batch.

Using a partition identifier: The partition id is set for a batch of events.  Because the partition is known upfront, this allows the batch to be routed to the partition directly, with no gateway intermediate operations to slow things down.  Once again, the entire batch must go to the same partition, as it is not possible to set different partition ids on individual events.


With respect to balancing, it depends on your publishing patterns.  If you're consistently publishing batches of the same size for automatic assignment, you'll see good consistent distribution of events in partitions.  If you've got an extreme spikey load, you're likely to see uneven distribution.
Partition keys can be tricky, because they're hashed on the service so you don't know the partition assignment upfront.  Generally, the distribution is good and event using keys.  However, there is the risk that you get unlucky with some patterns, and they end up causing hot partitions because of the mapping.
Partition identifiers are the most reliable, because you choose explicitly which partitions to send things to.  The trade-off here is that your application has to do more work to track load and select the best partition assignment to maintain balance.

Thanks for taking the time to answer. I understand the different partitioning strategies. What Im more interested to know is how is the actual network bandwidth for ingress and egress distributed across partitions. Do they all share the same bandwidth or is there a throttling allocation per partition on the ingress and egress? For instance, if I have 10 mb/second ingress, and 10 partitions (regardless of the strategy), does each partition get allocated 1mb/s or is 10mb/s across all partitions and random network ingress loadbalancing?

ah, gotcha.  I misunderstood what you were looking for.   A bit outside my wheelhouse, but I'm about 80% sure that I'm correct here.  The ingress quota and costs are between the sending machine and the Event Hubs gateway, so I wouldn't expect that to be split between partitions nor there to be any change based on which assignment method is used.   I'll also bring this to the attention of the Event Hubs PM and ask that they pop over and give you an authoritative answer.

@TheDaveJay thanks for this question.
The 1mb/s per partition is an empirical value that is not a hard throttle limit or a strict allocation.
